# How to connect amazon dynamo db to a react native app

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to react native and have to connect a AWS dynamo DB to a react native app. How can i connect and get data from it. Is there any other java connector or option to connect. which is the efficient method to do it.?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by `aws-amplify`. Following are some examples that, you can follow to learn more

- [AWS-Amplify](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/tutorials/building-react-native-apps/)
- [facebook-AWS-APP-Sync](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2018/03/05/AWS-app-sync)
- [aws-mobile-react-native-starter](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-mobile-react-native-starter)
- [react-native-training](https://medium.com/react-native-training/building-serverless-mobile-applications-with-react-native-aws-740ecf719fce)